# How do I split/subset a dataframe based on the distinct values of a specific column in python

Tags: python, pandas

How do I subset/split a dataframe based on the distinct values of column `UID`(see dataframe below)

```
import pandas as pd 

df = { 
         'UID':['A_1001', 'A_1001', 'A_1001', 'A_1001', 'B_1002','B_1002','B_1002','B_1002','D_1003','D_1003','D_1003','D_1003'],
        'X':[110.21, 191.12, 190.21, 12.00, 245.09,4321.8,122.99,122.88,134.28,148.14,161.17,132.17],
        'Y':[100.22,199.10, 191.13,199.99, 255.19,131.22,144.27,192.21,7005.15,12.02,185.42,198.00],
        'Z':[140.29, 291.07, 390.22, 245.09, 4122.62,4004.52,395.17,149.19,288.91,123.93,913.17,1434.85]
}
 
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
data
```

Desired output should store the 3 different dataframes based distinct `UIDs`- A1001, B_1002 and D_1003

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, v in data.groupby("UID"):
    print(i)
    print(v)
```

you can use `groupby` function.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, works fine, is there a more efficient way of storing the results as 3 independent dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

```
subset = []
for c in data['UID'].unique():
  a = data[(data["UID"] == c)]
  subset.append(a)
  continue

print(subset)
```

Comment: this only returns one of the three dataframes-  `D_1003`.

Comment: thanks for your attempt, however, I want to have 3 independent dataframes, stored as `df1`, `df2` and `df3` instead of storing all 3 dfs in `subset`.

Comment: subset is a list of dataframes you can select them by the index of subset. df1 = subset[0], df2 = subset[1]...This approach comes when you don't know how many unique values you have in the UID columns, if your the options of values in UID is limited, you can basically do: df1 = data[(data["UID"] == "A_1001)] and so on.